# constructor is not called after navigation to same component

Tags: angular

Please have a look at below code. I have updateValues() method to update the records this is edit case of form. after updating records i want to display listing of the added/updated records so i have navigate on same url on which i am currently. but the view is not refreshed because constructor is not called after navigation.

```
constructor(
        private MailService : MailService,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { 



    this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
        this.currentURL =  event.url;    
      }
    });

    this.getTemplates();
    this.formBuild();
}
updateValues(){
    // Call service for updating records.
    this.router.navigate([this.currentURL]);

}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you have to navigate to same place? Why not after updating values, fetch the values again from backend, instead of routing?

Comment: well, I don't want to fetch the values again and again as I have written getTemplates() for fetching values in constructor. after delete, update , add any operation, i wish constructor is called so automatically new value will be fetched through getTemplate() method.

Comment: I don't understand why on earth you would want to reinialize the whole component, when you can just call a method that updates the data?